# Turkish characters in URL

Tags: discussion, feature-request, profile-page

Turkish characters (such as ş, ğ, ı, ö, ü, ç) in the URL does not appear in a proper way.

I think user profile id's should be in a way like facebook does.

Lets say the user name is: Şenol Şahin then the user url should go something like senolsahin not enolahin.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Related on MSE: [Convert diacritics to normal letters in the profile link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214531/213963)

Comment: That's something I actually noticed too. It's trivial to convert foreign alphabets in ascii latin. Turkish Ş could be transliterated to *sh* or just *s* and as of Chinese *蒋中正* can be transliterated to *jiang zhong zheng*, Arabic khamsa *ح‎* to *7* or *kh* and so on. The only problem I see here is storage, as it requires a lot more especially in the case of Chinese. But I don't think the Stack Exchange team has to worry about that.